# next js react app just loading without stop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I am new to next js. just trying to convert a single html page to next js website so i can use sanity on it. I have been able to import every assets necessary but it just keeps loading and the preloader refuses to go away. I inspect the elements and realized a generated file called main-app.js is taking so long to load and I don't know what it does. Ok i tried to Manually removed the preloader and i saw that the page has loaded but i don't just know why the preloader cannot go away on its on as it is in the simple HTML file.

Please any contribution will be highly appreciated. here's the link to the repo and the live site on varcel:

site:
https://cios-pi.vercel.app/

github:

https://github.com/MagnificentRimsy/cios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `loader` function runs after the document has already loaded.

https://github.com/MagnificentRimsy/cios/blob/241682ecf27033b49ca32298dcdc351053690ef5/public/js/main.js#L45-L57

You probably need to execute the `onLoad` callback immediately if that's the case.

```
function loader() {
  const onLoad = () => {
    $("#ctn-preloader").addClass("loaded");
    $("#loading").fadeOut(500);

    if ($("#ctn-preloader").hasClass("loaded")) {
      $("#preloader")
        .delay(900)
        .queue(function () {
          $(this).remove();
        });
    }
  };

  if (document.readyState === "loading") {
    $(window).on("load", onLoad);
  } else {
    onLoad();
  }
}
loader();
```

Comment: ok please where can I execute it

Comment: or should i copy this code and replace what's there?

Comment: wow i copied the code and replaced what was there and it worked perfectly. thank you so much @igor_danchenko

Comment: @jonahrimsy, please fee free to accept the answer if it resolved your issue